# Rolling back transaction in channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a Spring Integration flow that polls a folder for a file and then tries to send the content of the file to a Kafka topic. The poller is configured to use a transaction manager (`PseudoTransactionManager()`), so that if something goes wrong the file is moved to a "error" folder.

This is how the flows look like:

```
  @Bean
  public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser
        .parseExpression("payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path " +
            " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
    syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(
        parser.parseExpression("payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundFailedDirectory.path " +
            " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
  }


public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource) {

    c -> c.id("inboundFileAdapter")
            .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)   
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor) 
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
              .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory()) 
                .transactional(transactionManager())))  
        // END POLLER CONFIGURATION
        .transform(fileToObjectTransformer)         
        .channel(INBOUND_BBS_CHANNEL)
        .get();
}



  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow toKafka(KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(INBOUND_BBS_CHANNEL)
          .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)

              .topic(this.properties.getEntitlement().getTopic())
            .sync(true)
            .messageKey(this.properties.getEntitlement().getMessageKey()))
        .get();
  }
```

The flow works perfectly in an "happy" scenario. But, if I kill the Kafka cluster, for instance, I would like the error to be propagated back and have the `transactionalManager` to move the file into the 'error' folder (and also log the issue using `wiretap`). Instead, when a Kafka-related error occurs I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
```

and then:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message payload must be an Expression instance or an expression String.
```

The file placed in the initial folder is not moved.
I assume that the problem is linked to  the fact that the "kafka channel" is one-way, therefore the exception is not propagated back to the initial flow, where the txManager lives. How can I get the txManager to "rollback" the file?

--- UPDATE ---

Complete stacktrace

```
2018-10-04 17:46:32.332 ERROR 7300 --- [ taskExecutor-4] o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener          : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='bbs.key' and payload='{"messageKey": "98d34db2-28c4-4b24-a867-5f16c4e662f6", "entitlements": [{"accountId": "030", "applic...' to topic bbs.topic:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.

2018-10-04 17:46:32.349  WARN 7300 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2018-10-04 17:46:32.348  INFO 7300 --- [ taskExecutor-4] ---- DONE ----                           : GenericMessage [payload={"messageKey": "98d34db2-28c4-4b24-a867-5f16c4e662f6", "entitlements": []
2018-10-04 17:46:32.364 ERROR 7300 --- [ taskExecutor-4] o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler                   : All attempts to deliver Message to MessageHandlers failed.; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [toKafka.org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"messageKey": "98d34db2-28c4-4b24-a867-5f16c4e662f6", "entitlements": [{"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T005917"}, {"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T005917"}, {"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "45T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "46T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "46T", "environment": "T011302"}]}, headers={errorChannel=error222, file_originalFile=c:\UBS\Dev\tmp\cosima-producer\inbound\read\full-base-lca17_126.txt, id=b28bb489-b62e-6861-5c1b-c4665fd72e62, file_name=full-base-lca17_126.txt, file_relativePath=full-base-lca17_126.txt, timestamp=1538667991063}]. Multiple causes:
    error occurred in message handler [toKafka.org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.
    error occurred in message handler [ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor@180d04d9] (inboundFileIntegration.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message payload must be an Expression instance or an expression String.
See below for the stacktrace of the first cause.org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [toKafka.org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"messageKey": ]}, headers={errorChannel=error222, file_originalFile=c:\UBS\Dev\tmp\cosima-producer\inbound\read\full-base-lca17_126.txt, id=b28bb489-b62e-6861-5c1b-c4665fd72e62, file_name=full-base-lca17_126.txt, file_relativePath=full-base-lca17_126.txt, timestamp=1538667991063}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:290)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$1.onCompletion(KafkaTemplate.java:370)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:768)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:363)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:355)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:257)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor@180d04d9] (inboundFileIntegration.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message payload must be an Expression instance or an expression String., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"messageKey": "98d34db2-28c4-4b24-a867-5f16c4e662f6", "entitlements": [{"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T005917"}, {"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T005917"}, {"accountId": "030", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "30T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "45T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "46T", "environment": "T011302"}, {"accountId": "046", "applicationId": "PAT", "accessRightType": "R2", "accessRight": "ALOE-SAP", "instanceCode": "46T", "environment": "T011302"}]}, headers={file_originalFile=c:\UBS\Dev\tmp\cosima-producer\inbound\read\full-base-lca17_126.txt, id=3ebb9873-e1c2-8ec3-b541-98106af7bf53, file_name=full-base-lca17_126.txt, file_relativePath=full-base-lca17_126.txt, timestamp=1538667991043}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message payload must be an Expression instance or an expression String.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: Especially for that `Message payload must be an Expression`. Thanks

Comment: updated with stack trace, thanks

Comment: Looks like you have somewhere a `Control Bus` defined for some channel. Please, show that code and it is really interesting how is that related to what you provided so far...

Comment: Yes, Indeed. I removed the `.controlBus()` from the first flow, for sake of simplicity. I need the `.controlBus()` because I need to dynamically turn on and off the flow. The Control Bus is on the `inboundFileIntegration` flow.

Comment: I have now added `.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "errorFlow", true))` to the starting flow, and I'm able to log exceptions. Interestingly enough, if I provoke an error in the `.transform()` method, the file gets "rolled back". But the file is not moved to the error folder when a kafka error occurs.

Comment: The `.controlBus()` cannot be as a part of regular flow unless you really call it and do something with its result. If that is only about `start/stop`, then a separate control bus flow must be defined.

Comment: So, please, update your question with the behavior when there is not control bus in the regular flow.